# Let $x=2+i$ be a root of $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ (where $a, b, c$ are real numbers). Given that $P(0)=5$, compute $P(1).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $x=2+i$ be a root of $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ (where $a, b, c$ are real numbers). Given that $P(0)=5$, compute $P(1).$

So, I remember seeing this problem on my homework a couple of months ago, and I wasn't able to solve it, and now I'm reviewing it and I still don't know how to solve it. :( I'd really like to learn how to solve it!

I don't really know where to start with this. Since they say that $P(0)=5$, then $c=5$, but that's all I've gotten so far. Can someone please help me solve it or give me a hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Use Complex conjugate root [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem), if $2+i$ is a root, so will be $2-i$

Now if $d$ is the last root using [Vieta's](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) [Formulas](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Vieta%27s_Formulas)
$$(2+i)(2-i)d=-c$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

From the comment, $5 d = -c$. Since $c = 5$ we have $d = -1$. The values of $a$ and $b$ follow from Vieta's formulas: $a = -(2 + i + 2 - i -1)$, i.e. $a = -3$ and $b = (2 +i)(2 - i) - (2 -i) - (2 + i)$, or $b = 1$, so that $P(1) = 1 -3 + 1 + 5$, or $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

$(2+i)^3 +a(2+i)^2+b(2+i) +c = 0$. So $(8 + 12i - 6 -i) + a(3+4i) + b(2+i) + c =0$ so $[2+c+3a+2b] + i[11+4a +b]=0$ so $3a + 2b+c+2=0$ and $4a+b+11=0$.

And $0^3 + a\cdot 0^3 + b\cdot 0 + c = 5$. So $c = 5$

$3a+2b+7=0$ and $4a+b+11=0$.  Solve for $a$ and $b$.

$3a+2b+7 = 4a+b+11$ and $b=a+4$ so $3a+(2a+8)+7=0$ so $5a=-15$ and $a=-3$.  $b=a+4 = -3+4=1$

So $P(1)= 1+a+b+c = 1-3+1+5=4$.